# Coda Slider not working in IE 7 javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coda-slider

Hi there I have coda slider working fine in `Chrome` ,`FF`,`IE 9`, but in `IE 6-8` its does not work the javascript debugger say that line line of code:

```
$container.css('width', $panels[0].offsetWidth * $panels.length);
```

its says:

```
Unable to get value of the property 'offsetWidth': object is null or undefined
```

Any helpl with this would be great thanks

Comment: Try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203959/0-offsetwidth-is-null-or-not-an-object-coda-slider-javascript-error-ques  Could be useful

Comment: The JavaScript is only one the page that requires it.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try [outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) (jQuery method) instead of offsetWidth.

Comment: Bvukelic   do you mean replace 'offseWidth' with outerWidth()  tried that but still no go..tanks anyway.

Comment: @user1041401 try with `$panels.eq(0).outerWidth()`.

Comment: Hi I replaced    $panels[0].offsetWidth with    $panels.eq(0).outerWidth() but still not working..thanks anyway

Comment: Any more help out there? Thanks

Comment: @user1041401: Does it give you an error message when you replace `offsetWidth` with `outerWidth()`?